# VBA obtaining info from unopened workbook from shared drive

Tags: vba, excel

I'm curious about what the format of a code in VBA for...

obtaining specific rows from a specific sheet from a specific workbook within a specific subset of folders.

for example: Populating Sheet1 in Wkbk1 from the data in Sheet1 from Wkbk2 which is in a shared drive somewhere....

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I realize this may be a vague post so I am going to try to explain in further detail.

I am looking for a code which allows me to do the following.

- Enable a macro from WkBk 1 to pull data from WkBk 2.
- WkBk 2 is located within a shared drive and is closed.
- I want to pull specific data from WkBk 2 and populate that data into specific rows in WkBk 1.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I'll try to explain better. My macro so far does some basics, but I need to copy data from a shared drive to my opened workbook. The workbook I want to copy FROM is closed. Let's assume my shared drive is S:\Me\letsshare\thisfile. This is where the file I want to pull from is located and from within "thisfile" I want to pull specific rows from a specific sheet. I have no idea which function I should use to start this process...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code below can be made more exact or efficient, but it will get you started:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PullFromFile()

Dim wkb as Workbook, wkbFrom as Workbook

Set wkb = ThisWorkbook '-> assuming the workbook you want to copy to has code in it
Set wkbFrom = Workbooks.Open("S:\Me\letsshare\thisfile.xlsx")

Dim wks as Worksheet
Set wks = wkbFrom.Sheets("mySpecificSheet")

Dim rng as Range
Set rng  = wks.Rows("1:3") '-> set your specific rows, here

rng.Copy wkb.Sheets("whichSheet").Range("A1") '-> adjust to your settings

wkbFrom.Close False

End Sub
```